# Selenium KeyDown for keys not in the modifier

Tags: selenium

As I know, selenium keyDown(keyUp) method is only available for keys in modifiers (SHIFT, ALT, CTRL). I need to press SPACE key a certain amount of time.

I have a questions about key event handling in Selenium keyboard interface.

**1. Why selenium does not permit keydown and keyup event for other general keys ?**

**2. Is there any workaround to achieve this goal ?**

For now, I used Robot class to implement this, but I don't want to use this.

Answer (score 1):

since you didn't tell us which Selenium-binding you are using, I will show my examples in Java, you may transcode them into any binding you please:

you can press the SPACE key via the `sendKeys()` method:

```
driver.sendKeys(Keys.SPACE);
```

I don't know why you would want to use the `keyDown() keyUp()` methods for the "general keys" you are talking about, you can also use `sendKeys()` for most objectives:

```
driver.sendKeys("a");
```

You can use the Actions class if you want to combine normal key-actions with `keyDown()/keyUp()` actions

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("c").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
```

for example to copy something via `CTRL+c`...

Comment: thanks for replying. Yes I'm using selenium java. The reason why I want want use keyDown event for SPACE is following. 1. My target web page contains some video playing contents, and it needs to keep SPACE bar pressed a certain amount of time (for example, if you press SPACE bar 10 seconds, next page will be shown. I know this is not general in common web site UI, but this is mandatory requirement for me.